# Como posso mudar a classe da div que o usuário clicou, sendo que tenho várias divs com o mesmo nome

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Eu tenho uma lista de card com a mesma classe. Eu queria saber como posso fazer para que quando alguem clicar no card, o card que ele clicou mude para a classe "active" e seja selecionado o checkbox.

HTML:

```
<div class="cardFlex">
    <div class="card">
       <input type="checkbox" id="debitCheckbox" />
       <p>12x de R$144,50</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
       <input type="checkbox" id="debitCheckbox" />
       <p>12x de R$144,50</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
       <input type="checkbox" id="debitCheckbox" />
       <p>12x de R$144,50</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.sideFlex').find('.card').click(function () {
    $('.sideFlex').find('.card').toggleClass('active');
})
```

Comment: se passar o `this` como parametro do click, vai saber exatamente qual elemento foi clicado. O `this` nesse caso vai ser o elemento quem disparou o click

Comment: Show de bola, funcionou! 

Agora, como posso fazer para que quando ele clicar nesse card, o input[checkbox] ficar como checked?

Comment: Eu queria também fazer um script para que ele possa selecionar apenas um card, tipo um input[radio] mesmo. Se ele clicar em 1 card, o outro que ele tinha selecionado é desmarcado

Comment: Fala Amigo. Minha estratégia seria através de uma função, capturar o event.target e setar nele a nova classe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui um exemplo.

Ao adicionar um handler para o evento `click`, é passado para a função o elemento que disparou o evento, que pode ser acessado com `$(this)`.

No exemplo abaixo, usei o seletor `$(".card")`, que vai retornar todos os elementos com a class "card", ou seja, quando entrar na *function*, `$(this)` vai retornar o elemento clicado, dentre os elementos com a classe "card".

A partir daí é só usar esse elemento para aplicar a class, veja abaixo:

```js
$(".card").click(function() {
  $(".card").removeClass("selecionado");
  $(this).addClass("selecionado");
});
```

```css
.selecionado {
   background-color: cyan !important;
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="cardFlex">
    <div class="card">
       <input type="checkbox" id="debitCheckbox" />
       <p>12x de R$144,50</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
       <input type="checkbox" id="debitCheckbox" />
       <p>12x de R$144,50</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
       <input type="checkbox" id="debitCheckbox" />
       <p>12x de R$144,50</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Opa, funcionou!! 
Agora, como posso fazer para que quando ele clicar nesse card, o input[checkbox] ficar como checked?

Comment: Ah já consegui!

`$(".sideFlex").find(".card").click(function () {
        $(".card").removeClass("active");
        $(".card").find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
      });`

Comment: ia comentar isso, precisava "deselecionar" todos e usar um find pra selecionar o input filho na div :)